# How to add a property to a map dynamically in velocity?

Tags: dictionary, velocity

I have the following code

```
$pageName = "test";

$Container = {};
```

I like to set a property of `$Container` by a variable. I tried `$Container.set("test", $pageName);`. It didn't raise any errors, but `$Container.test` or `$Container.get("test");` display nothing.

How do I fix it?

Comment: ah..sorry guys..just found the solution. instead of using set, I need to use put

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that set is the wrong method.  You need to do a put.  Remember - Velocity is calling the Java methods.  There is no "set" method on a Map object.

Specifically, you can do

```
$Container.put("test", $pageName)
```

Now, one weird thing is that this will print "true" or "false" in the page, since the Map.put() method returns a boolean.  So I always do

```
#set($dummy = $Container.put("test", $pageName))
```

which does the put and stores the result in another reference (which you can then ignore) instead of rendering it to the page.

Comment: What if you want to itterate over the keys in a map and dynamically update it? I'm finding that when you "$value = $arr.get($key)" the value of a key, amend it, and then "$arr.put($val)" that all the entries in the map end up as the last one put, because they all refer to the the same "$val"

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ran into the same problem is the "true" or "false" printed on the page, and there is a simpler way to handle it.  What I did is a little weird, and I did it Confluence, which of course uses Velocity under the covers.  I mention that because I understand Velocity can be used in may different applications.

With a Confluence user macro, I check for a previously created attribute on the req variable, the request variable, i.e. "myPageVars".  Then I use the put method to put a new key-value pair, based on the macro parameters.  By using the $! prefix, rather than just $, the output isn't sent to the screen.

...
$!req.getAttribute("myPageVars").put( $paramKey, $paramValue )
...

I'm somewhat new to Velocity, so I can't guarantee this will work in every context, but it seems syntactically easier than the whole #set ($dummy etc. line.